# MDX Query for Filtering Non Empty Values

Tags: ssas, mdx, dashboard, performancepoint

I need to create a filter in Performance point Dashboard to get only non empty values. I am trying to write a MDX Query for selecting the values

```
SELECT NONEMPTY{[H School ].[Dist Name], [H School ].[School Name]}

FROM  [Early Cube ]
```

but it is not filtering the data

Comment: This is a good initial resource for *trivial* mdx: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145506.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for non-empty cells against some measure. In other words, the dimension members need to be empty or non-empty against 'some set', such as a measure. There are two ways of doing this depending on whether you want your measures to be shown in your result.

1. NON EMPTY clause in SELECT:

   It displays cells obtained from intersection between measures on one
   axis and dimension members on the other axis, thereby eliminating the  `(null)` values.

   ```
   SELECT 

   /*Measures*/
   {[Measures].[Customer Count]} ON 0,

   /*NON EMPTY clause against Dimension members*/
   NON EMPTY {[Customer].[Customer Geography].[City]} ON 1 

   FROM [Adventure Works];
   ```
2. [NONEMPTY() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145988.aspx):

   > Returns the set of tuples that are not empty from a specified set, based on the cross product of the specified set with a second set.

   ```
   SELECT 

   {} ON 0,

   /*NONEMPTY() FUNCTION*/
   NONEMPTY([Customer].[Customer Geography].[City], [Measures].[Customer Count]) ON 1 

   FROM [Adventure Works]
   ```

More detailed difference between these two approaches can be found [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/2996/non-empty-vs-nonempty-to-the-death) and [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/65/posts/11569/mdx-non-empty-vs-nonempty.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Here in the query:

```
SELECT NONEMPTY([H School ].[Dist Name], [H School ].[School Name])

FROM  [Early Cube ]
```

Can you rewrite this as:

```
SELECT NONEMPTY([H School ].[Dist Name]*[H School ].[School Name], <<add your measure/context here if you do not want to use the default measure>>)

FROM  [Early Cube ]
```

Comment: Is this a new question or an answer? If it is an answer then I have marked it down as you have not even labelled the axes in the `SELECT` clause. If it is a new question then please start a new question.